# Kabalevski Op. 48 (Violin) - What is this called and how do you play it?

Tags: theory, notation, practice, violin

First of all, I'm sorry for the unspecific title, but since I don't know what it is called, I cannot specify.

I'm regarding the last bar before they key switches from Eb Major (2 b) to C Major (no alterations). Above the g, there is some sort of diamond-shaped note.

What is this called and how do I play it?[image]

Edit: Here is a link to a [recording](https://youtu.be/CPwozlKnkuU?t=89) available on YouTube. The thing that I refer to can be heard at about 1:28.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_harmonic), specifically a fingered harmonic. When you put your first finger down to plat the G you shorten the string. To play this harmonic you then very lightly rest another finger (usually the 4, because that's the right distance) on the same string so that it is a quarter of the way along the vibrating part of the string and combine it with a very fast, light bow-stroke. This gets the string vibrating with one sound wave between the two fingers combining with 3 equal length waves between the higher finger and the bridge to produce a note two octaves above the G that would sound if just the first finger were down.

Here is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue90f5r-2Qw) giving more explanation and examples.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the ways of notating *flageolet* effects. Briefly, it means to play a normal g and simultaneously touch the string where you would play the c above. The result is a g sounding two octaves above the notated g.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So in this case I would just put my finger one fourth above the g (which would be the c)?

Comment: Yes, the perfect fourth grip is the most common artificial flageolet by far; it produces nice high notes, and the two points of contact conveniently fit your fingers 1 and 4.